# Запись строк в файл при помощи StreamWriter

Tags: c#

Каким образом при помощи StreamWriter можно записать символы в определённую строку? Например, так выглядит файл. Нужно "Василий" записать в первую строчку, "31" во вторую..
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если нужно записывать форматно (в определенной последовательности), то делают предварительно сериализацию объекта(ов), а потом уже пишут в файл то, что получилось после сериализации.

Comment: @FoggyFinder я ещё не знаком с этим

Comment: Если вы не будете пробовать узнавать что-то новое, то никогда не выйдите дальше своего уровня. Дерзайте!

Comment: Используйте TextWriter если работаете с текстом, и его метод WriteLine

Answer (score 1):

Вот без сериализации, используя `ToString()`

```
class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string WorkPlace { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Имя: {this.Name},{Environment.NewLine}Возраст: {this.Age},{Environment.NewLine}Рабочее место: {this.WorkPlace}";
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person person = new Person()
        {
            Age = 31,
            Name = "Вася",
            WorkPlace = "Цех самоубийц"
        };

        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        path = Path.Combine(path, "people.txt");

        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.Write(person.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```